# How to get the last line from reader.ReadString if there is no newline character

Tags: parsing, go

I've been writing this Php parser in Go, but I seem to have hit a little problem, which is that sometimes the final line is not added to the new file I am writing.

Basically I go over the original Php file, do some obfuscating, and then write those obfuscated lines to a new file.

Problem is that at times I run into a file that does not have a newline at the end, and I assume that `line, err := reader.ReadString('\n')` will not read a string if it does not have the delimiting character at the end?

Is there an easy solution for this that doesn't involve using Scanner, because a lot of the parsing code is dependent on interpreting newlines...

Comment: "and I assume that [...] ReadString('\n') will not read a string if it does not have the delimiting character at the end". Your assumption is wrong. See e.g. https://play.golang.org/p/Mc2D17Dovnh

Comment: Hmm, you are right... There must be something else wrong then. It's strange, because as soon as I add a newline to the last line in the original file, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I was breaking out of the loop before adding the last character to my obfuscated line. Moving the EOF handling to the bottom resolved it.

Comment: You should provide the code so others can reference this. I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot comment yet, this is my answer to @Kyle Bridenstine

I experimented the same issue with the following script (extract below) :
https://github.com/setsuna-/golang/blob/master/mass_replace.go

By moving the error test from line 88 to line 93, the last line of source files ending by
} without a new line character are now correctly copied to the destination file.

```
bufr := bufio.NewReader(f1)
bufr2 := bufio.NewWriter(f2)
for {
    line, err := bufr.ReadString('\n')
    if strings.Contains(line, searchText) {
        line = strings.Replace(line, searchText, replaceText, -1)
        count++
    }
    bufr2.WriteString(line)
    if err != nil {
        break
    }
}
bufr2.Flush()
```